# Is this the right way to open object from DB for editing in the same form, and then saving the updated value for the same object using django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

This is my code:

To create the new issue object, use form

```
def raise_issue_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    
    form = RaiseIssueForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()

        obj = RaiseIssueModel.objects.latest('id')
        return redirect("/raise_issue/" + str(obj.id))
    
    context = {
        "form" : form
    }

    return render(request,"raise_issue.html", context)
```

To edit the previously created issue, by link 127...8000/edit_issue/<issue_id>

```
def edit_issue_view(request, id):
    obj = RaiseIssueModel.objects.get(id=id)

    form = RaiseIssueForm(instance=obj)
    new_form = RaiseIssueForm(request.POST, instance=obj)
    

    if new_form.is_valid():
        
        new_form.save()
        
        return redirect("/raise_issue/" + str(obj.id))
    
    context = {
        "form" : form
    }

    return render(request,"raise_issue.html", context)
```

Here, in Edit issue view, first i'm loading the DB data into 'form', then I'm creating a new form (new_form) to save the updated data.
Is this OK, or is there a better way to do this?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works but is not correct...
The validated form is the *new_form*. If it is invalid, you will display the errors from *form* (which does not have any error since it hasn't been submitted).

You also failed to check if the object exists.

```
def edit_issue_view(request, id):
    try:
        obj = RaiseIssueModel.objects.get(id=id)
    except RaiseIssueModel.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404()

    form = RaiseIssueForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj)
    
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        
        return redirect("/raise_issue/" + str(obj.id))
    
    context = {
        "form" : form
    }

    return render(request,"raise_issue.html", context)
```

Then, for your first form. The save() method of your form should return the created object (assuming you used a django.forms.ModelForm). So you can write it this way:

```
def raise_issue_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    
    form = RaiseIssueForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        obj = form.save()
        return redirect("/raise_issue/" + str(obj.id))
    
    context = {
        "form" : form
    }

    return render(request,"raise_issue.html", context)
```

Comment: This is working great! I tried
    `form = RaiseIssueForm(request.POST, instance=obj)` before and it wasn't working,
but after adding '` or None`' to that, it's working fine.
This is much cleaner, and thanks for explaining the flaws in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GET` and `POST` requests to do different functions. GET for fetching the object from DB and POST to make the changes and saving it to DB. For example:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def edit_issue_view(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(RaiseIssueModel, pk=id)
    new_form = RaiseIssueForm(request.POST or None, instance=obj)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if new_form.is_valid(): 
            new_form.save() 
            return redirect("/raise_issue/" + str(obj.id))
    
    context = {
        "form" : new_form
    }

    return render(request,"raise_issue.html", context)
```

Also add a minor change in `raise_issue_view` method regarding the redirecting to edit view. As you can see, `form.save()` returns the object you just created/updated. You can use that for redirecting:

```
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save()
    return redirect("/raise_issue/" + str(obj.id))
```

Finally, for redirecting, it is better to use named urls. For example, if your url looks like this:

```
path('raise_issue/<int:pk>/', name='raise_issue')
```

Then you can use the following code to redirect:

```
return redirect('raise_issue', pk=obj.pk)
```

For more information, please see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is working as well, and yes I have modified my code to include `obj = form.save()` this is much cleaner, I'll be reading more on `redirect`